# Dispatcher.Main raising exception

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {}

raising exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException.

It is working fine for all other dispatchers(IO, Default etc..)

## Main.kt

```
    package com.app.suspendingfunctions.kotlin

    import kotlinx.coroutines.*

    fun main() {
        
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {}
    
    }
```

## coroutine dependency

```
    //coroutines

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"
```

**Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.missing(MainDispatchers.kt:118)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.isDispatchNeeded(MainDispatchers.kt:96)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:319)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.suspendingfunctions.kotlin.MainKt.main(Main.kt:6)
    at com.app.suspendingfunctions.kotlin.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@1a3869f4, Dispatchers.Main[missing, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!]]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher(HandlerDispatcher.kt:55)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatchersKt.tryCreateDispatcher(MainDispatchers.kt:57)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherLoader.loadMainDispatcher(MainDispatchers.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherLoader.<clinit>(MainDispatchers.kt:22)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.getMain(Dispatchers.kt:57)
    ... 2 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.missing(MainDispatchers.kt:118)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.isDispatchNeeded(MainDispatchers.kt:96)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:319)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.suspendingfunctions.kotlin.MainKt.main(Main.kt:6)
    at com.app.suspendingfunctions.kotlin.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelled}@1a3869f4, Dispatchers.Main[missing, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!]]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher(HandlerDispatcher.kt:55)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatchersKt.tryCreateDispatcher(MainDispatchers.kt:57)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherLoader.loadMainDispatcher(MainDispatchers.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherLoader.<clinit>(MainDispatchers.kt:22)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.getMain(Dispatchers.kt:57)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried changing the coroutine version and tried adding a couple of statements to proguard-rules.pro file as suggested in Github issue "https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/932" but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread is a UI thread so a Main Dispatcher doesn’t exist if you aren’t using a library with a UI like Swing or JavaFX or Android. You must also add the coroutine library for that specific UI system for it to exist.

Comment: I have added the android version of coroutines library.

Comment: implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"

Comment: But you’re using it from `main()`, which isn’t an Android entry point, so there is no Android UI present.